# Can't send the real-time output of a subprocess with a websocket

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket

I'm writing a server which can run a set of commands, and send the output of those commands to a browser via a websocket. I'm using `Flask-SocketIO`. Using code like this, I'm able to send a bunch of messages to the client:

```
def echo_a_bunch(thing):
    for _ in range(1, 11):
        socketio.emit('message', {'data': thing}, namespace="/test")
        socketio.sleep(0.5)

@socketio.on('echo', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    build_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    socketio.start_background_task(echo_a_bunch, message['data'])
```

When I have the corresponding code set up on the client, I can send an "echo" message and have it sent back 10 times, every half-second.

But what I really want to do is stream the output of a subprocess back. Let's try to do the same thing instead using a subprocess:

```
def echo_a_bunch(thing):
    bash_cmd = "for _ in $(seq 1 10); do echo '{}'; sleep 0.5; done".format(thing)
    cmd = ["bash", "-c", bash_cmd]
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        thing = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
        socketio.emit('message', {'data': thing}, namespace="/test")
    proc.wait()
```

In this case, the same data ends up getting sent, but it doesn't get to the client until the entire command has completed, so about 5 seconds.

I'm not sure why this is the case, but I suspect it has to do with the blocking read on the process' stdout? Maybe I need to yield the thread somehow, or use a different library (something async) to read the process?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Facing a similar issue!